# I'm getting error of driver .exe not exist on the path given?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm learning selenium and while running my 1st practice script which is pasted below i'm getting the error of driver exe not exist on the path though i have tried to paste exe file of chrome driver on different locations and then gave the path and re run the script. But all the same i'm getting this error over and over again please help me to figure it out:

**Practice Script Is:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class PracticeSelenium {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/");
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='emailid']"));
        element.sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");

        WebElement button=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='btnLogin']"));
        button.click();
    }
}
```

**Error/Exception is:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=49519:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\rt.jar;E:\Python\JavaSelenium\out\production\JavaSelenium;I:\selenium-java-3.14.0\client-combined-3.14.0.jar;I:\selenium-java-3.14.0\libs\byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar;I:\selenium-java-3.14.0\libs\commons-codec-1.10.jar;I:\selenium-java-3.14.0\libs\commons-logging-1.2.jar;I:\selenium-java-3.14.0\libs\commons-exec-1.3.jar;I:\selenium-java-3.14.0\libs\guava-25.0-jre.jar;I:\selenium-java-3.14.0\libs\httpclient-4.5.5.jar;I:\selenium-java-3.14.0\libs\httpcore-4.4.9.jar;I:\selenium-java-3.14.0\libs\okhttp-3.10.0.jar;I:\selenium-java-3.14.0\libs\okio-1.14.1.jar" PracticeSelenium
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Downloads\chromedriver.exe
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:346)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at PracticeSelenium.main(PracticeSelenium.java:10)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Is the file C:\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe there ?

Comment: yeah i've pasted it there

Comment: Try downloading the proper driver as per your chrome version. Try by replacing your driver file with https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.23/

Answer (score 0):

```
public static WebDriver driver;

public class PracticeSelenium {
public static void main(String[] args){
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");

driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/");
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='emailid']"));
element.sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");

WebElement button=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='btnLogin']"));
button.click();
    }
}
```